RPI 4B Max Number of BLE Connections
So I have a RPI 4B and it's currently communicating with an IMU via BLE for sensor data that I need to send to the web via mqtts for a project I'm working on. (For clarification, this IMU is currently set up as a bluetooth server that is advertising it's service uuid till a connection is established, after this i set my raspberry pi that is acting as a ble server to subscribe to the characteristics that the imu is sending)
Based on the research I could find, it seems like there is apparently a max number of connections that the RPI can hold at a time. However, this number seems to keep changing (sometimes it's stated to be 8, 10, or even 24 connections in various forums.)
How many connections should the RPI ACTUALLY be able to sustain without any major changes to the firmware? (From my understanding, the cypress CYW43455 ble chip and the available ram on the board are the major limiters of this number and are at default a max of 8)
On top of this, what steps would I need to take to increase the max number of connections from the default? (I'm aiming for upto 30 connections but I need AT LEAST 20.)
What other solutions should I look into? (I've heard about the nrf52840 dongles but I'm not to confident in their range and any information on that could also be helpful)
Lastly, I understand if information on this is low, but i was also looking to switch to a raspberry pi zero2W due to it's smaller form factor but if the RPI 4B is unable to handle at least 20 connections then it may not make sense to switch to that device. if not (what's another recommending piece of hardware for this solution? I would like to stay away from just soc's as i don't have enough knowledge to create custom boards)
